# Snakemake issues running rules on two different subsets of wildcards

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I am attempting to write a snakemake rule that will treat some files, based off their `grouping` differently than others. My file list is loaded in in a sample.tsv file.

I thought this would be relatively easy as I believed that populating the wildcards in the `rule all` would trigger execution of particular  rules, but that does not appear to be the case.

Here is a paired down version of what I'm working on

List of sample files. Note that the `chip` category here is what becomes important for defining my groups

```
tissue replicate chip file
leaf rep2 input 00.data/chip_seq/input/leaf_input_rep2.fastq
leaf rep1 input 00.data/chip_seq/input/leaf_input_rep1.fastq
leaf rep2 H3K36me3 00.data/chip_seq/H3K36me3/leaf_H3K36me3_rep2.fastq
leaf rep1 H3K36me3 00.data/chip_seq/H3K36me3/leaf_H3K36me3_rep1.fastq
leaf rep1 H3K56ac 00.data/chip_seq/H3K56ac/leaf_H3K56ac_rep1.fastq                                                                                                        
leaf rep2 H3K56ac 00.data/chip_seq/H3K56ac/leaf_H3K56ac_rep2.fastq
```

In my script I have then divided these into two sub-categories

```
broad = ['H3K36me3']
narrow = ["H3K56ac"]
```

```
rule all:
    input:

#Align all reads
expand("02.unique_align/{tissue}_{chip}_{replicate}_unique_bowtie2_algn.bam", \
    ¦   ¦   ¦   tissue = samples['tissue'], replicate = samples['replicate'], \
    ¦   ¦   ¦   chip = samples['chip']),

#Should cause the expand on ONLY narrow groups, causing the below rule
# run_bcp_peak_caller_narrow to trigger 
expand("03.called_peaks/{tissue}_{replicate}_{chip}_peaks_region_narrow.bed",
    ¦   ¦   ¦   tissue = narrow_peaks['tissue'],
    ¦   ¦   ¦   replicate = narrow_peaks['replicate'],
    ¦   ¦   ¦   chip = narrow),

#Should cause the expand on ONLY narrow groups, causing the below rule
# run_bcp_peak_caller_broad to trigger

expand("03.called_peaks/{tissue}_{replicate}_{chip}_peaks_region_broad.bed",
    ¦   ¦   ¦   tissue = samples['tissue'],
    ¦   ¦   ¦   replicate = samples['replicate'],
    ¦   ¦   ¦   chip = broad)


## Two functions, one to get the input files, defined here as `get_input` the other to retrieve the chip files

def get_input(wildcards):
    z = glob.glob(os.path.join("02.unique_align/", (wildcards.tissue + "_" + \
    ¦   wildcards.replicate + "_" + "input_unique_bowtie2_algn.bam")))
    return z

def get_chip(wildcards):
    z = glob.glob(os.path.join("02.unique_align/", (wildcards.tissue + "_" + \
    ¦   ¦   ¦  wildcards.replicate + "_" + wildcards.chip + "_" + \
    ¦   ¦   ¦  "unique_bowtie2_algn.bam")))

    return z

rule run_bcp_peak_caller_broad:
    input:
    ¦   chip_input = get_input,
    ¦   chip_mod = get_chip
    params:
    ¦   "03.called_peaks/{tissue}_{replicate}_{chip}_peaks_broad"
    output:
    ¦   "03.called_peaks/{tissue}_{replicate}_{chip}_peaks_broad.bed"
    shell:"""
    peakranger bcp \
    --format bam \
    --verbose \
    --pval .001 \
    --data {input.chip_mod} \
    --control {input.chip_input} \
    --output {params}
    """

rule run_bcp_peak_caller_narrow:
    input:
        chip_input = get_input,
        chip_mod = get_chip
    params:
        "03.called_peaks/{tissue}_{replicate}_{chip}_peaks_narrow"
    output:
        "03.called_peaks/{tissue}_{replicate}_{chip}_peaks_narrow.bed"
    shell:"""
    peakranger \
    --format bam \
    --verbose \
    --pval .001 \
    --data {input.chip_mod} \
    --control {input.chip_input} \
    --output {params}
    """
```

Error is as follows:

```
MissingInputException in line 39 of /scratch/jpm73279/04.lncRNA/02.Analysis/24.regenerate_expression_peaks/Generate_peak_lists.snake:
Missing input files for rule all:
03.called_peaks/root_rep1_H3K4me1_peaks_region_broad.bed
03.called_peaks/root_rep2_H3K36me3_peaks_region_broad.bed
03.called_peaks/leaf_rep1_H3K4me1_peaks_region_broad.bed
03.called_peaks/root_rep1_H3K36me3_peaks_region_broad.bed
03.called_peaks/leaf_rep2_H3K36me3_peaks_region_broad.bed
03.called_peaks/root_rep2_H3K4me1_peaks_region_broad.bed
```

My understanding is that snakemake populates the files combinations found in the `rule all` section and then identify what steps need to be run upstream.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in your understanding; when no output is specified to snakemake it will find the first rule, and try to generate its output.

The problem is that `rule all` specifies rules that can not be 'made'. I'll show a side-by-side comparison of the mistake:

```
rule all:
    03.called_peaks/root_rep1_H3K4me1_peaks_region_broad.bed

rule run_bcp_peak_caller_broad:
    output:
        "03.called_peaks/{tissue}_{replicate}_{chip}_peaks_broad.bed"
```

See the difference? The files you say you want to generate end with `peaks_region_broad.bed`, however your rules make output ending with `peaks_broad.bed`.

Take a look again at `rule all` and probably you want to remove the **_region** part of the strings.

Comment: Wow, that's it. I can't believe i missed that. Thank you!